# Button not working on first click with if and else statements

Tags: javascript, buttonclick

I am trying to make the navigation work on first click of the button. But for some reason the button won't work on first click and works fine on second click

```js
function authenticate() {
  let x = document.getElementById('aut').value;
  if (x == 'code') {
    document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
    };
  } else {
    alert('Please check your password')
  }
  console.log('If this message appears in the console, JavaScript is running.');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="auth">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="auth" id="aut">
  <button id="myButton" onclick="authenticate()">Authenticate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Walk through what happens when the user clicks the button. What code is executed? What does it do?

Comment: Seems to work fine; I entered nothing, clicked the button, it alerted "Please check your password" and logged "If this message appears in the console, JavaScript is running.". I entered "code", clicked the button, it logged "If this message appears in the console, JavaScript is running.". and that's it. I clicked the button the last time, it redirected to google.com.

Comment: Assigning a new `onclick` handler doesn't mean it gets executed right away. The button was clicked previously, that caused `authenticate()` to run, but it will need to get clicked again for your inline function to get called. (and `authenticate()` won't get called again)

Comment: Assigning event listeners within event listeners is usually a very bad idea. Just redirect to the new URL if the conditions are right. There's no need for the extra `onclick = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first click, you only changed the button's onclick handler, not execute it.
On second click, you executed the changed handler.
It seems like you don't need to change the handler, just execute it right away.

```
function authenticate() {
  let x = document.getElementById('aut').value;
  if (x == 'code') {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
  } else {
    alert('Please check your password')
  }
  console.log('If this message appears in the console, JavaScript is running.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this without declaring the authenticate function:

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
  let x = document.getElementById("aut").value;

  if (x == "code") {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
  } else {
    alert("Please check your password");
  }
  console.log("If this message appears in the console, JavaScript is running.");
};
```

EDIT:
Or, if you want to use the function style:

```
function authenticate() {
  let x = document.getElementById("aut").value;

  if (x == "code") {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
  } else {
    alert("Please check your password");
  }
  console.log("If this message appears in the console, JavaScript is running.");
}
```

Or, even better as suggested in the comments, using event listener:

```
const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let x = document.getElementById("aut").value;

  if (x == "code") {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
  } else {
    alert("Please check your password");
  }
  console.log("If this message appears in the console, JavaScript is running.");
});
```

Comment: Even better would be to use `addEventListener('click', function...` instead of the old style `onclick = `.

Comment: True, but I wanted to preserve the existing code as possible.